# (UILabel) nil, Cannot insert text in the label

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift4, uicontainerview

Good day,

I seem to have such a simple problem but I just can not wrap my head around it.

I have a container view inside a view controller. In that container I have few labels. The container has its own view controller. In the view controller for the container I have a timer running and I want that label to show the timer. But every time I use that label the app crashes with 
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

If I comment the line out that has this label then everything runs fine.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

var counter = 0.0
var timer = Timer()
var isRunning = false


func startStopTimer () {
    if isRunning {
        timer.invalidate()
        isRunning = false
    }else {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isRunning = true
    }
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    counter = counter + 0.1

    timeLabel.text = String(counter) 
}
```

This is the first time I play around with container view in the Main storyboard.

Anyone that knows what I am doing wrong or has suggestion what I can try to change?

Thanks
Jonas

---

Full Code

```
    class MainViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var topContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var informationContainer: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var startStopButtonOutlet: UIButton!

let informationContainerVC = InformationContainerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupView()
}

func setupView() {
    topContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    topContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true

    informationContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    informationContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true

    startStopButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    startStopButtonOutlet.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

@IBAction func startStopButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    informationContainerVC.startStopTimer()

    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }, completion: nil)

    if informationContainerVC.isRunning {
        startStopButtonOutlet.setTitle("Push to Pause", for: .normal)
    }else {
        startStopButtonOutlet.setTitle("Push to Start", for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func startStopButton_TouchDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseIn], animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)

        if self.informationContainerVC.isRunning {

            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        }else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        }



    }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func startStopButton_TouchUpOutside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Here is the code for the container view controller

```
class InformationContainerViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

var counter = 0.0
var timer = Timer()
var isRunning = false


func startStopTimer () {
    if isRunning {
        timer.invalidate()
        isRunning = false
    }else {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isRunning = true
    }
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    counter = counter + 0.1

    timeLabel.text = String(counter)

}
}
```

Comment: Check if the outlet is connect to the storyboard.

Comment: It is connected to the correct label.

Comment: When is startStopTimer called?

Comment: startStopTimer is called from a button on the mainViewController. This container is on the same view controller as the button.

Comment: You might want to share the full code of both your classes.

Comment: Make sure that you have connected the outlet to correct viewcontroller. if the label is in viewcontroller A it must be connected to VC_A

Comment: I believe its connected to the correct VC. I have posted the whole code.

Comment: The information view controller is not loaded. So the outlet is never connected. You have to have a segue or code to push or present the view controller from the first view controller. Not create a new instance of the inside the class and just call it. When do you want the information view controller to appear and call the timer?

Comment: I want to have the container visual at the same time as the main VC. I just used the container view so it would be easier to adjust the size of everything inside it between devices. But I would like the timer to start running as soon as you press the startStopButton.

Comment: From what i understood you dont need a second viewcontroller. Just hide and show the container as and when needed in the same view controller

Answer (score 0):

When you say `let informationContainerVC = InformationContainerViewController()` you are creating a new instance of `InformationContainerViewController` that is not linked to the storyboard, so none of the outlets are set.

You need to get a reference to the view controller instance that is actually in your container view.  You can do this in `prepare(for segue:)`; If you look at your storyboard you will see that there is an embed segue that links your containing view controller to the contained view controller.

In your MainViewController:

```
var informationContainerVC: InformationContainerViewController?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destVC = segue.destination as? InformationContainerViewController {
        self.informationContainerVC = destVC
    }
}

@IBAction func startStopButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    informationContainerVC?.startStopTimer()

    UIButton.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseOut], animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }, completion: nil)

    if informationContainerVC?.isRunning {
        startStopButtonOutlet.setTitle("Push to Pause", for: .normal)
    } else {
        startStopButtonOutlet.setTitle("Push to Start", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Now you will have a reference to the correct view controller instance